# Seal edge of mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

Have used a shrinkwrap to make a mesh and trimmed of the bits I didn't want, however this has left the edge very messy and full of holes. I could go round the edge and tidy it up manually but this would take a very long time. Is there a simple fill all the holes and make it solid again?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're just trying to fill in the holes. To do this, select the edges around the holes (use Shift+Alt+Right Click) and press F to fill them in.

Comment: This is a small part of a very large mesh. I have started going round the edge and doing manually but was really wandering if there was a quick, easy automated method.